# Filter a list for sums

Tags: scheme, racket

I need to write a function which consumes a list of integers lst and produces a list containing only the unique elements of lst (in no particular order) that are a sum of any two other elements in lst.

Ex:

```
(sumfilt '(1 4 7 5 17 11)) => '(11 5)
(sumfilt '(5 4 7 5 9 1 10)) => '(5 9 10)
```

Can someone help me with this please? I also want this to make this as efficient as possible

Comment: and what have you tried so far, besides coming here and have us doing your homework or so ? Show us some code !

Comment: I have only formulated what I think it should be. I am planning to make another function that consumes the 1st value of the list, and take the rest of the list, and see if there's any 2 values there that makes up that 1st value. I am still thinking about this though, not sure if that's the most efficient way.

Comment: Keep thinking then, and come back afterwards with some code. cfr http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask to see what is or not an acceptable question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you some *hints* to solve this. A first naïve approach, would be to precalculate a list of sums of each of the size-2 combinations of the input list and then test to see which of the input lists' elements belong in the list of sums. As a final step, remove the duplicates.

Assuming that a `comb` procedure exists for calculating all possible combinations of the `lst` list with a given size `m` (look for it, or implement it yourself!), here's a very short answer for the problem, implementing the naïve algorithm explained above - which should be good enough for lists with 1000 elements or so:

```
(require srfi/26) ; I like to use `cut`, but `lambda` would serve just as well

(define (comb lst m)
  <???>) ; ToDo: generate all m-size combinations of lst

(define (sumfilt lst)
  (let ((sums (map (cut apply + <>) (comb lst 2))))
    (remove-duplicates (filter (cut member <> sums) lst))))
```

Or equivalently, using `cute` for evaluating the precalculated list of sums only once:

```
(define (sumfilt lst)
  (remove-duplicates
   (filter (cute member <> (map (cut apply + <>) (comb lst 2))) lst)))
```

A more efficient approach would involve some variation of the [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) problem, solved by means of dynamic programming. Such a solution would be more elaborate to write, though. Either way, don't forget to test your answer:

```
(sumfilt '(1 4 7 5 17 11)) 
=> '(5 11)

(sumfilt '(5 4 7 5 9 1 10)) 
=> '(5 9 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your question is tagged *Racket*, I'd like to suggest a solution with Racket idioms:

*allsums* creates the list of all sums, as suggested by Oscar. It's basically a nested loop which processes all the necessary combinations. In order not to have duplicates, I use a *set* which silently drops them when added. Later the set is converted to a list.

```
(define (allsums lst)
  (let* ([len (length lst)] [len-1 (sub1 len)])
    (set->list
     (for*/set ([i (in-range 0 len-1)]
                [j (in-range (add1 i) len)])
       (+ (list-ref lst i) (list-ref lst j))))))
```

*sumfilt* now filters your list against the list produced by *allsums*. Again, a set is used to drop the duplicates:

```
(define (sumfilt lst)
  (let ([as (allsums lst)])
    (set->list
     (for/set ([i lst] #:when (member i as))
       i))))
```

Such as

```
> (sumfilt '(1 4 7 5 17 11))
'(5 11)
> (sumfilt '(5 4 7 5 9 1 10))
'(5 9 10)
```

But if you need to have a pure Scheme solution, this code will do, using only the classical forms and idioms:

```
(define (allsums lst)
  (let loop1 ((lst lst) (res '()))
    (if (empty? lst)
        (reverse res)
        (let loop2 ((a (car lst)) (bs (cdr lst)) (res res))
          (if (empty? bs)
              (loop1 (cdr lst) res)
              (let ((s (+ a (car bs))))
                (loop2 
                 a 
                 (cdr bs) 
                 (if (member s res) res (cons s res)))))))))

(define (sumfilt lst)
  (let ((as (allsums lst)))
    (let loop ((lst lst) (res '()))
      (if (empty? lst)
          (reverse res)
          (let ((ca (car lst)))
            (loop 
             (cdr lst) 
             (if (and (member ca as) (not (member ca res)))
                 (cons ca res)
                 res)))))))
```

giving

```
> (sumfilt '(1 4 7 5 17 11))
'(5 11)
> (sumfilt '(5 4 7 5 9 1 10))
'(5 9 10)
```